# How tho check this checkbox (capybara/ruby)

Tags: javascript, ruby, selenium, capybara

How to check this checkbox?[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KXfrD.png)

I tried:

```
  within('div[id="modalPersistEtapa"]') do

                 element = @driver.find_element(:xpath, '//*[@id="2018_4"]/i')
                 @driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();"
```

No success! =(

I got this error:

```
  element click intercepted: Element <i class="i i-logout"></i> is not clickable at point (1878, 56). Other element would receive the click: <div class="modal fade bs-example-modal-lg in" id="modalPersistEtapa" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myLargeModalLabel" aria-hidden="false" style="display: block;">...</div>
    (Session info: chrome=87.0.4280.88) (Selenium::WebDriver::Error::ElementClickInterceptedError)
  Backtrace:
    Ordinal0 [0x012DC0C3+3326147]
```

...

Comment: From the error, it sounds like you need to change the box sizes or z-order of elements. Since there's no executable or testable code in your question, you're unlikely to get a full answer.

Comment: Please use newlines in code so that it fits the window.

Comment: There is a parenthesis missing at the end of your code.

Comment: Please include the HTML for the whole row containing the thing you're trying to click on in your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't use direct driver calls or execute_script to try and click on things - if you're having to do that you're doing something wrong.

```
within('div[id="modalPersistEtapa"]') do
  find(:xpath, './/*[@id="2018_4"]/i').click();
  ...
end
```

Generally for things like this I'd also recommend using CSS rather than XPath but XPath may make sense here since you'd have to escape an id starting with a number in CSS. Also note the ".//" in front of the XPath - without the dot it makes the `within` pointless since the XPath will escape scope.

If that doesn't work for you then trying to do it via other means is just making your tests worthless.

Comment: So thank you!! I tried: find(:xpath, '/xpath...', visible:false).set(true) and worked!! it's a invisible element, so i set visible:false. I think was that =)

Comment: @Mary Interacting with non-visible elements is not guaranteed to work (because a user can't interact with them) and may break at any time.  If you add the HTML for the whole row to your question I can probably tell you what you should be doing.